# cordova-plugin-googleplus token for reading the gmail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gmail-api, google-plus-signin

I have a cordova app that uses google plus login.  Can you use the same token generated by cordova-plugin-googleplus to read a user's email by making a gmail-api call?

Comment: Have you tried checking the process [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-googleplus)?

Comment: Yes I know how to make login work.  The question is can you access a user’s inbox with the same token?